# In MS Outlook VBA, why a type mismatch on this call to MailItem.Move?

Tags: vba, outlook, type-mismatch

The method [`MailItem.Move`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.move) has the syntax:

```
<MailItem>.Move(<Folder>)
```

The following display image shows the code I'm running, two watches, and the error they give:

[image]

When the error occurs and I click "Debug", the code comes up with yellow highlighting on the line:

```
oMailItem.Move (oDestFolder)
```

The watches show that `oMailItem` is of the correct type `MailItem` and `oDestFolder` is of the correct type `Folder`. The watch window also shows the names of those objects, indicating that they exist.

So, why the type mismatch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to get rid of `()`:

```
oMailItem.Move oDestFolder
```

Comment: That did it. Thank you. Another error in MS documentation, since the doc page linked in the question has the folder in parens. Do you know why putting it in parens causes an error? Mathematically, a quantity in parens is the same as the quantity without parens. But here, putting the object in parens changes it.

Comment: It is VBA - `()` means a function. You can also fix it by assigning a function return value `set oMailItem = oMailItem.Move(oDestFolder)` or by using `call`: `call oMailItem.Move(oDestFolder)`